# npm error ENOENT

Tags: node.js, npm

When I tried to check global modules I got `ENOENT` error, what is wrong and how can I avoid such error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. type `npm install` and hit Enter.
2. Check issue still exists. and If issue not resolved, continue these
   methods. type `npm cache clean`
3. type `sudo npm install -g npm`
4. Retry `npm install`
5. `npm init`

let me know if that fix the problem